# Apache Mod Security-Core rule set issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-security

In my application I have implemented mod security and as it's generic for few URL I have blocked few rules for particular location (URL). But I am OWASP error with below URL and not getting able or finding the way to block rules for this URL.

So please help me to block the rule for the below issue. The error log is given below. Thanks in advance.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 499
Host: accountingdev.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_72)
Cookie: FA512c3d57865ef2662e9b1421f5c4d8ad=3pr1b0illdbem2kq9f99kfrpn2
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

--a42de647-C--
logoutRequest=%3Csamlp%3ALogoutRequest+xmlns%3Asamlp%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Aprotocol%22+ID%3D%22LR-24-AHmvxyBBAudEaobzuTMpXrdPtmmVhiUU1ed%22+Version%3D%222.0%22+IssueInstant%3D%222016-10-14T17%3A20%3A00Z%22%3E%3Csaml%3ANameID+xmlns%3Asaml%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Aassertion%22%3E%40NOT_USED%40%3C%2Fsaml%3ANameID%3E%3Csamlp%3ASessionIndex%3EST-47-zdTNWjTqaSAbtxbpBPca-abc.com%3C%2Fsamlp%3ASessionIndex%3E%3C%2Fsamlp%3ALogoutRequest%3E
--a42de647-F--
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Location: https://portal.com/caa/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Faccountingdev..com%2F
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
csrf-token: D=20647 t=1476445738526589
Content-Length: 493
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Can you show the rule that is supposed to block this request that is not working?

Comment: I want to off the rule set for this particular url.

Comment: Which rule? Or do you want to turn off all rules for this URL?

Comment: Yes. I want to turnoff all the rule for this particular url.

Comment: The url is "/" which is the home page. It is possible to turn off all rules for the homepage, or for requests including "logoutRequest" in the body if that's what you want. Alternatively it may be better to explain which rule is firing and just excluding that rule for these requests. At the moment your question is unclear as to what the problem is and what you want to do.

Comment: If I block with "/" in location match then will it off the rules for all other url's as "/" is the context path? 

"At the moment your question is unclear as to what the problem is and what you want to do" - My requirement is very simple. On logout I am getting owasp errors. So, would like to block the rules or the rule engine off for this particular url.

Comment: What error is it giving? From Apache error log. You have given the audit log which does not show any ModSecurity error.

Comment: Error is coming on mod security audit log. It's showing content type/sql injection and few other errors on content-type.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show those errors?

Comment: This errors are specifc to my environment. So, what I want is simply switch of rules for this url. But the question is if I switch off for "/" then will rule work for all other url as "/" is the context path.

Comment: Any suggestion to block the request specific to logout request

Answer (score 0):

You could write a rule like this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "POST" "phase:1,id:1234,pass,log,chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_URI "/" "ctl:ruleEngine=Off"
```

This should turn ModSecurity off for any POST requests made to the home page (untested). This is of course quite broad and may remove protection from other POST requests made to the home page that you want to check.

Alternatively you could do this to only search for this specific request:

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "POST" "phase:2,id:1234,pass,log,chain"
   SecRule REQUEST_URI "/"
       SecRule ARG_POSTS:logoutRequest "LogoutRequest" "ctl:ruleEngine=Off"
```

However this would need to be a phase 2 rule, to look at the POST arguments - which are in the BODY and so not available in phase 1. This may mean that phase 1 rules fire before it even gets to this rule.

A **much** better idea is to tune the rules that are firing, but that involves telling us which rules they are which you seem hesitant to do. So can't help you much with that until you do.